# Creating Tables with MYsql in yii 1.1

Tags: php, mysql, yii, yii-components

Here is the scenario: I have been following the "yii" book by Larry Ullman in which he gave his MYsql for CMS but he didn't described any tool , how to create these tables of sql. The only way I know is through migrations but the sql written in the book is not working in migrations.

The sample sql is given for a table from the book :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS yii_cms.user ( id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
username VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL, 
email VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL, 
pass CHAR(64) NOT NULL, 
type ENUM('public','author','admin') NOT NULL, 
date_entered TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
PRIMARY KEY (id), 
UNIQUE INDEX username_UNIQUE (username ASC), 
UNIQUE INDEX email_UNIQUE (email ASC) ) 
ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT 
CHARACTER SET = utf8
```

Comment: What is exactly the question? Do you need some tool to create tables in MySQL or do you want to create table programmatically in yii?

Comment: I want to create the tables in yii from this sql

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind, you can use straight-forward way to execute sql so:

```
$sql = 'your sql here';
Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql)->execute();
```

The other way is to use Yii QueryBuilder and the createTable() command. More information for QueryBuilder is [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.query-builder) and for createTable() [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCommand#createTable-detail).

Comment: Where to write this command ?? File name or the procedure could help alot

Comment: You can write it some controller file or in some cronjob-script.

Comment: Can you help me in creating tables through migrations using this sql ?

Comment: Please refer to the official documentation then:
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.migration

Comment: But this sql does'nt work in migrations thats the main problem ... i know how to use migrations but this sql is not working :(